# Insert nested objects into multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oop

I have an object I want to add to a MySQL database using CodeIgniter / PHP. The problem however is that it has arrays of other objects as well that need to be inserted (or updated).

A simplified example of what I mean:

Tables in the database:

```
+----------+
| Order    |
+----------+
| - id     |
| - name   |
| - date   |
+----------+

+-------------+
| Orderline   |
+-------------+
| - orderId   |
| - productId |
| - amount    |
+-------------+
```

Example of an object I want to insert:

```
$order->name = “John Doe”

$orderline1 = new stdClass();
$orderline1->productId = 1;
$orderline1->amount = 10;

$orderline2 = new stdClass();
$orderline2->productId = 2;
$orderline2->amount = 5;

$order->orderlines = array($orderline1, $orderline2);
```

So I want to insert these in the database, 1 row in the Order-table and 2 rows in the Orderline-table. I'm using CodeIgniter (because I have to). I know how to insert an object and how to get the last inserted ID. But I am not sure about nested objects and I also will have to add the orderId to all the orderlines first.

What I have so far:

```
$this->db->insert('Order', $order); // no clue what will happen to the $order->orderlines doing this
$orderId = $this->db->insert_id(); // to get the id to add to the orderlines

// a loop to add the orderId
foreach($order->orderlines as $orderline){
    $orderline->orderId = $orderId;
}

// to insert the orderlines
$this->db->insert_batch('orderline', $order->orderlines);
```

I'm not sure what will happen when inserting the order as there is no row in the Order-table called orderlines. **Will it be ignored or cause an error? Is this a good way or am I doing it wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

$this->db->insert('Order', $order->name);

Also you can use [rollback method](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) for cases of unsuccessful query.

Comment: The real stuff has way more properties, the example in the post was to simplify it.

Comment: About 'nested objects'. If it is in scope, it can be read nevertheless it is array element plain variable, object property or something else.
I don't see why wouldn't it be interpreted as value.